# Sorting words by their freq in python

Tags: python, list, sorting, python-3.x

```
import sys
def candidateWord():
   filePath = "sample.txt"
   file = open(filePath,'r')
   word_count = {}
   for line in sys.stdin.readlines():
         for word in line.split():
            #words = word.lower()
            words = word.strip('!,.?1234567890-=@#$%^&*()_+').lower()
            word_count[words] = word_count.get(words,0) + 1

         for key in word_count.keys():
            #sorted(word, key = str,lower)
            print (str(key)+' '+str(word_count[key]))

candidateWord()
```

How would I sort the words I have in a textfile by their frequency using what I have already?

The text file (sample.txt) contains the following: `How are you How are you I am good. HBHJKOLDSA How`

My desire output should be:

```
how 3
am 2
are 2
i 2
you 2
good 1
hbhjkoldsa 1
```

I am working in python 3.

Answer (score 5):

Use the [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects):

```
from collections import Counter

with open("sample.txt", 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()

words = [w.strip('!,.?1234567890-=@#$%^&*()_+') for w in text.lower().split()]

counter = Counter(words)

print(counter.most_common())
# [('how', 3), ('are', 2), ('you', 2), ('good', 1), ('i', 1), ('am', 1), ('hbhjkoldsa', 1)]
```

Your desired output:

```
print("\n".join("{} {}".format(*p) for p in counter.most_common()))
```

Using your code and sorting by (frequency desc, word asc):

```
for key, value in sorted(word_count.items(), key=lambda p: (-p[1], p[0])):
    print("{} {}".format(key, value))
```

The Counter result can be sorted in the same way, just replace `word_count.items()` with `counter.most_common()`.

Comment: Is it possible to use the collections.Counter with files instead of just text?

Comment: Of course. Why are you opening a file and then reading from `stdin`?

Comment: Here, I replaced `text` with contents of a file.

Comment: So replace everything I have with yours and it will be complete?

Comment: Yes, but if this is an assignment you probably should implement your own Counter-like procedure?

Comment: I will but there is one more thing. "i" should be behind "are" and "am" in the desired output

Comment: I don't know what's in your file or what you're piping to stdin, but your provided example only has one `I`.

Comment: Meaning the word "i" should be alphabetized after "am" and "are" since their frequency are the same.